# how to update fetch with useLoaderData() using react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, fetch, react-router-dom

I would like to update the data of useLoaderData() after submit a form.
In my case :

```
export const countriesLoader = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all/");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw Error("Could not reach the data !");
  }
  return res.json();
};
```

`<Route index element={<CoutriesList />} loader={countriesLoader} />`

on CountriesList element :

`const countries = useLoaderData();`

new data that i would like to update in countries useLoaderData()  :

```
const findCountry = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(
      `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${searchText}`
    );
    const data = res.json();

    return data;
  };
```

So when I submit, I would like that the data of countriesLoader to become the data from findCountry.

any solution ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may be looking to use `findCountry` as a route action when a form is submitted. Loaders run when a route is loaded for the first time. An action can be dispatched later.

Basic Example:

```
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    index: true,
    element: <CountriesList />,
    loader: countriesLoader,
    action: findCountry
  }
]);

<RouterProvider router={router} />
```

```js
const countriesLoader = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all/");
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw Error("Could not reach the data !");
  }
  return res.json();
};
```

```js
const findCountry = async ({ request }) => {
  const formData = await request.formData();

  const res = await fetch(
    `https://restcountries.com/v3.1/name/${formData.get("country")}`
  );
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw Error("Could not reach the data !");
  }
  return res.json();
};
```

```
import {
  Form,
  useActionData,
  useLoaderData
} from "react-router-dom";

const CountriesList = () => {
  const searchResult = useActionData();
  const countriesData = useLoaderData();

  return (
    <>
      ...

      <Form method="post" replace>
        <label>
          Search <input required type="text" name="country" />
        </label>
        <button type="submit">Create</button>
      </Form>

      ...
    </>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit how-to-update-fetch-with-useloaderdata-using-react-router]

Comment: wow this is the solution ! but it doesnt work on my project ? any idea why ? https://codesandbox.io/s/naughty-sammet-3vjood?file=/src/components/CoutriesList.jsx

Comment: i want to replace all the list of the countries with the country that we search

Comment: @mdnc If I had to guess it might just be that the component needs to conditionally render one result set or the other. Taking a look in the sandbox.

Comment: @mdnc Nice app. It turns out it was a couple issues: (1) there's a `onSubmit` handler on the `Form` that prevents the default action, and (2) the `action="/"` was a problem since the `CountriesList` is rendered as an index route under `MainLayout`. It turns out that `action` is really only needed if the form needs to submit against a different path in the app. Here's a [fork](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-update-fetch-with-useloaderdata-using-react-router-im4ntk?file=/src/components/CoutriesList.jsx) of your sandbox that looks to be running as you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much I understand the problems now ! 
but I feel limited with your request because now I want to add a filter by region which is provided with the api by : https://restcountries.com/v3.1/region/${regionl};

But i can't use a second action in the <Route> right ? I don't know how to approach this, any idea ?

Comment: @mdnc You can likely submit different forms, and handle the branching factor in the action function based on what is passed in the `request` prop. Are you trying to wire up the region dropdown?

Comment: @mdnc Check this implementation: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-update-fetch-with-useloaderdata-using-react-router-forked-oi3pq1?file=/src/components/CoutriesList.jsx